# LWC: is the Standard Tab component firing app events when switching tabs?

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab

Is there any hidden event available to be subscribed in order to capture when the user selects a tab from the standard tab component(added from the app builder)

Inside each tab, we've placed our own LWC components. If an event is available, we can implement the handler for that inside all the content components and get our work done.

**Note**: some of the options like `currentPageReference` and `renderedCallBack` seems not working probably as we need this in the service console.

Answer (score 0):

`connectedCallback` lifecycle hook is called the first time the component loads, but there's no guarantee when that will be called. The `renderedCallback` handler should fire each time a tab becomes active, but of course, will also fire each time a wire method refreshes the component or any tracked properties update, so you'd have to account for that. In summation, there doesn't appear to be any guaranteed, dedicated event you can listen for.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I think I missed the important information that we are trying this inside the service console tab. `renderedCallback` not firing from the second time onwards when we come back to a last visited tab

Comment: @highfive A screenshot of what you're trying to do exactly would be helpful. I've made some assumptions based on your wording.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following method to detect when tab is changed

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

@wire(CurrentPageReference)
setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
    this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Patlatus, I forgot to mention that we are trying this inside the service console. The shared approach is not working in the console application unfortunately